# Choosing a event entry client view framework

Tags: php, database, frameworks, content-management-system, web

I have a front end event entry system (basically a booking interface) and back end view (for the client) written in PHP. For some very good reasons, I cannot continue to use the existing back end view for the clients.

The back end view is basically a small PHP site, that allows a client to view their entries, search, add entrys and make modifications.

My question is: Are there any good existing platforms that I could use as a base for this back end, and what are the pros/cons of each approach?

**Requirements**: All it has to do is hook in to an existing database (mysql) and allow different views, modifications and searches (for a number of different clients).

I have seen there are existing CMS packages (Drupal etc) and was wondering whether these may be the kind of framework I'm looking for.

Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks!

Note: I have experience in many programming languages/areas of computer science, but not so much in the area of web apps/programming.

Comment: SO is not a site to recommending scripts, if you have a programming question then ask it

Comment: The choice of framework is clearly going to affect my programming questions (probably lack of) in the future, so consider yourself saved by a pre-emptive question. Also, if your going to be rude, learn to write properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you look at either [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). You will have to define metadata for your model (sort of duplicating your database DML to a small extent) but both frameworks then allow you to quickly build up a scaffold admin interface (django does a better job of creating a pretty powerful admin interface to start with). Here's an example of the model in both frameworks:

database DML:

```
CREATE TABLE myapp_person (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL
);
```

Rails model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Django model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```